# vscode doesn't show code action (import python function from python.analysis.extraPaths)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, pylance

I try to import a function (print_pretty_table) which is located in pretty_table_yaml_json

so I add the following code to setting.json, it doesn't give 'show code action' which could help me do "from pretty_table_yaml_json.api import print_pretty_table"

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "/home/xxxx"
 ],
 "python.analysis.autoSearchPaths":true,
```

but if I copy  pretty_table_yaml_json.api to /home/xxxx,it could give the right "show code actions" which help me "from pretty_table_yaml_json.api import print_pretty_table" as expected.

any help ?